# IIS7 Performance Issues for Web-services

Tags: performance, web-services, iis-7

We are experiencing slow processing of requests under heavy load. When looking at the currently running requests during these bursts I can see many requests to our web-service code.

The number of requests is not that large but they appear to be stuck in a preprocessing state. Below is an example:

We are running an IIS7 app pool in classic mode due to the need to support some legacy code.

Other requests continue to be processed but these stuck requests gradually seem to fill up the available threads leading to slow processing of other pages.

Does anyone have any idea on where these requests are getting stuck.

There appears to be no resource issue with the DB and the requests state show suggest this is all preprocessing.

We have run load tests on the code involved on local machines and can not replicate the issue.

Another possible factor is we are making use of MVC and UrlRouting.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues only happen at production servers unfortunately, as load test can never simulate real world users.

You can try to capture hang dumps when performance is bad, and then analyze them (on your own or open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to work with Microsoft support).

Usually you might have hit the famous thread pool bottleneck, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821268. Dump analysis can easily tell the culprit and help locate a solution.

Comment: Performed debbug diag which pointed at a component, no entirely convinced but working with vendor. When it comes to it this is about insufficient threads. Still researching if there is anyway to increase this simply with IIS7 ASP.NET4 and Classic Mode. Thanks for help.

Comment: The KB article does inform how to increase threads. Before the vendor resolves the issue completely, you might try to manually tune the threads. That's a common workaround which works in some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Why not move them into their own AppPool to separate them from the Classic ASP app - you'll then have more options to tune.